# How can I get rid of \r\n in my text file

Tags: python, regex, replace, newline

I'm working on a project that generates text based on lyrics and I'm having issues getting rid of \r\n in my text files. Here is an example of some output:

> b" the chuwt flexer, Larr\r\nPull up welds pinky ring\r\n\r\nLil Pumpy, yuh, I hagete I me natch on houssed that xxxx a cracklee\r\nI was muse shenting like I'm cockouks on your med to your my a claboy what?\r\nPoll yual' a selll phowe i's wens higner rack, ooh (ooh rije I way? (yuh)\r\nHo righ"

The \r\n's appear whenever a new line should appear. I've tried several implementations using .replace() and .rstrip() on a line by line basis to get rid of them but they don't seem to work. If it matters, the text file is encoded in UTF-8.

I'm working in Python as well as PowerShell, so a solution in either is acceptable.

EDIT: Here is one approach I tried (and failed) to use.

```
f = open("input.txt",'r')
filedata = f.read()
f.close()

newdata = filedata.replace(r"\r\n","\n")

f = open("output.txt",'w')
f.write(newdata)
f.close()
```

Comment: what have you tried that doesn't work. Because you seemed to be in the right direction.

Comment: Is that exactly what you see when you open your file in a text editor? A lowercase letter B and a quote mark, etc...?

Comment: you may consider a less offensive text as well.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I'll edit my OP with one of many implementations that didn't work.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre haha it was just the data I had on hand. didn't want to run the program again from scratch just to generate sample text. 
lil pump is also good to use for something like this since he only has like 50 songs to analyze

Comment: `str(the_string, 'utf-8').replace('\r\n', ' ')`

Comment: @Kevin yes, exactly that. the b" is a bug I need to squash still

Comment: @srig that gives me a typeerror (TypeError: decoding str is not supported)

Comment: If the character sequence "\r" is plainly visible in the text of your file when viewed with Notepad or whatever, the reason that `.replace("\r", "")` isn't doing anything is because the file does not contain any "\r" characters. It contains "\" characters, followed by "r" characters, but that is not the same thing as a carriage return. Perhaps you could remove them with `.replace("\\r", "")`, but that's ultimately a bandaid solution; you need to find out why the files are being written like this in the first place. Solve the `b"` issue and you'll solve this issue too, most likely.

Comment: @honestlywtf_man, are you using Python 2?

Comment: @Kevin I 100% agree that the bandaid solution isn't ideal, and I should look to fix this bug at the source, but I'm really mystified as to why my approach isn't working. I know that escape characters need to either have `\\\`` or an `r` before the string, but using .replace() isn't working even with one of those two.
So it's pretty much just being stubborn at this point

Comment: @srig nope, 3.6

Comment: `the_string.replace(b'\r\n',b' ')`. Your string is a `bytes` object

Comment: @honestlywtf_man, I've tried it at [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/DearKnowingAtlasmoth). It is working.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, I get `TypeError: replace() argument 1 must be str, not bytes`

Comment: @srig interesting, that exact code works on my machine too. maybe it has something to do with how python reads from a text file?

Comment: ok then `the_string.replace('\r\n',' ')`. [mcve] please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input is of the type `bytes`. On Python 3.x, this should work:

```
the_string = b" the chuwt flexer, Larr\r\nPull up welds pinky ring\r\n\r\nLil Pumpy, yuh, I hagete I me natch on houssed that xxxx a cracklee\r\nI was muse shenting like I'm cockouks on your med to your my a claboy what?\r\nPoll yual' a selll phowe i's wens higner rack, ooh (ooh rije I way? (yuh)\r\nHo righ"

print(type(the_string))
print(str(the_string, 'utf-8').replace('\r\n', ' '))

<class 'bytes'>
 the chuwt flexer, Larr Pull up welds pinky ring  Lil Pumpy, yuh, I hagete I me natch on houssed that fuck a cracklee I was muse shenting like I'm cockouks on your med to your my a claboy what? Poll yual' a selll phowe i's wens higner rack, ooh (ooh rije I way? (yuh) Ho righ
>>>
```

This also should work:

```
the_string.decode().replace('\r\n', ' ')
```

Comment: I'm starting to wrap my head around this; I'm still getting the following error though:

`TypeError: decoding str is not supported`

any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: sounds that this question is bad. noone seems to find the issue.

Comment: @srig I think I see part of the problem. Right now I'm reading the file and getting a string: b"....." which is basically a string containing a bytes-type string. So can I somehow cast it back to being bytes and then use your method to replace the characters?

Comment: which is the comment that Kevin posted 45 minutes ago...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yep, I'm slow. really appreciate everyone's effort helping me here though

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, you're right :)

Comment: @srig I'm using bits and pieces of github code - and I found that a part of it encodes files as utf-8. so I'm running the program through again, just without the encode bit. Hopefully that resolves it

Comment: @honestlywtf_man, not a problem :)

Comment: @srig YEP, that was it. Took out the `encode()` and everything was lovely.

Comment: @honestlywtf_man, glad I could be of some help :)

Answer (score 1):

Opening a file for reading with universal newline mode ('rU'), known line endings are replaced by '\n'. Nevertheless the mode parameter is now deprecated, but can be used `newline=None`. According with [Python 3.5.4 documentation](https://docs.python.org/release/3.5.4/library/functions.html#open):

> When reading input from the stream, if newline is None, universal
>   newlines mode is enabled. Lines in the input can end in '\n', '\r', or
>   '\r\n', and these are translated into '\n' before being returned to
>   the caller.

So you can give it a try,

```
f = open("input.txt",newline=None) # Deprecated f = open("input.txt",'rU')
filedata = f.read()
f.close()

f = open("output.txt",'w')
f.write(filedata)
f.close()
```

Comment: no, doesn't seem to work unfortunately

Comment: It should work because opening a file for reading with universal newline mode ('rU'), known line endings are replaced by '\n'.